# an array of char pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to use an array of char pointers where each pointer in the array is pointing to a char in another char array, therefore, I would be able to print the char array through the pointers.

```
char city[14] = {'D', 'u', 'b', 'a', 'i'};
char *charPointers[100] = {0};
for(size_t i = 0;city[i] != '\0'; i++)
    charPointers[i] = &city[i];
printf("\ncity = ");
for(size_t i = 0; *charPointers != 0; i++)
    //printf("%c", *(charPointers[i]));
    putchar(*charPointers[i]);
```

Is charPointers an array of pointers or simply a string ?
If it's a string, then how can I use an array of pointers such that each pointer is pointing to a char?
What's an elegant way to achieve what I want? (preferably using pointer arithmetic)

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `charPointers` is an array of pointers; it is not a string.  Your second part of the question is moot.  You ask "What's an elegant way to achieve what I want" without explaining what you do want.

Comment: I've stated what I wanted from the code at the very beginning. I would like to have an array of char pointers to point to each character in the city[14] array.

Comment: If you really want 14 character pointers, you need to run your loop setting the pointers 14 times, not just 5 times.  However, that aside, your pointer initializing code works; you end up with a pointer to each non-null pointer in the `city` string.  As I diagnosed in my answer, your printing loop has a flawed terminating condition.  You should really be showing, or describing, the output you get.  You probably get the city name followed by garbage and eventually a crash, but it would be better if you said that.  My answer shows how to fix the problem in plausible ways.  What more do you want?

Answer (score 1):

`charPointers` is an array of pointers; it is categorically not simply a string.

Since it isn't a string, your second question is moot.

Your loop condition is incorrect; you need to write:

```
for (size_t i = 0; charPointers[i] != 0; i++)
    //printf("%c", *(charPointers[i]));
    putchar(*charPointers[i]);
putchar('\n');
```

You're testing whether the first pointer is null; it isn't.  You need to check the current pointer on each iteration.  The loop below might help you understand what's going on, too:

```
for (size_t i = 0; charPointers[i] != 0; i++)
    printf("%zd [%s]\n", i, charPointers[i]);
```

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char city[14] = {'D', 'u', 'b', 'a', 'i'};
    char *charPointers[100] = {0};
    for(size_t i = 0;city[i] != '\0'; i++)
        charPointers[i] = &city[i];

    printf("city = ");

    for (size_t i = 0; charPointers[i] != 0; i++)
        putchar(*charPointers[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    for (size_t i = 0; charPointers[i] != 0; i++)
        printf("%zd [%s]\n", i, charPointers[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

produces this output:

```
city = Dubai
0 [Dubai]
1 [ubai]
2 [bai]
3 [ai]
4 [i]
```

Answer (score 1):

`charPointer` is an array of pointers to `char`. A pointer to an array of char would be `char (*p)[100];`.

Your code is near correct, here is the not-segfaulting version :

```
char city[14] = {'D', 'u', 'b', 'a', 'i', '\0'};
char* charPointers[100] = {0};
size_t i =0;
for(i = 0; city[i] != '\0'; i++)
    charPointers[i] = city + i;

charPointers[i] = city + i; // Don't forget to add the \0 at the end !

printf("\ncity = ");
for(i = 0; *charPointers[i] != '\0'; i++)
    printf("%c", *charPointers[i]);
```

I don't really know what you want to do, but the code above is storing a pointer to each character of the string `city` in each element of `charPointers`.

However, if you want to store a pointer to existing string in `charPointers` (for instance, each element of `charPointers` points to a city name), here would be the correct code:

```
char* cityNames[NB_CITY];
char* city = "Dubai";

cityNames[0] = city;
printf("%s\n", cityNames[0]); // gives "Dubai"
```

Answer (score 0):

`charPointers` is clearly an array of pointers to characters.  The array `city` is a string (as pointed out in a comment) since you've specified a length of 14 but only provided 5 actual characters. The rest are set to zero which will terminate the string.

A much clearer way to get the same result would be:

```
const char *city = "Dubai";
```

Your loop over `*charPointers` is strange, since it treats `*charPointers` as a character, when it's really a pointer.

Perhaps you meant:

```
for(size_t i = 0; charPointers[i] != NULL; ++i)
  printf("%s\n", charPointers[i]);
```

Comment: Actually it is properly terminated; if a brace-enclosed initializer does not include enough initializers for all elements, then the other elements are zero-initialized.

Comment: I see. So how can I use charPointers to point to each char in char array city[14], thus allowing me to print city character by character through the the charPointers ?!?!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Brain error. I rewrote it. I would never rely on initialization like that to make a string, it's way too obscure.

Comment: To be fair, I think the OP null terminated it by luck rather than intentionally... at a glance, it looked like an obvious bug to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use an array of char pointers where each pointer in the array is pointing to a char in another char array

Why? There is never a reason why you would want to do this, in real world programming.

> therefore, I would be able to print the char array through the pointers

Indeed. That's handy if your program is too fast and too effective.

> Is charPointers an array of pointers or simply a string?

It's an array of pointers.

> What's an elegant way to achieve what I want?

There is no elegant way to "use an array of char pointers where each pointer in the array is pointing to a char in another char array". This is obfuscation and it fills no purpose except making your code slow and unreadable.

Sane, elegant code would look like this:

```
const char city [] = {'D', 'u', 'b', 'a', 'i', '\0'}; 

printf("City = ");
print_str(city);

...

void print_str (const char* str)
{
  while(*str != '\0')
  {
    putchar(*str);
    str++;
  }
}
```